# How to move data one table to another table older than 30 days record?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am developing chat apps.

I have two table `messages` and `message_archives` both table column is same.

My `messages` table containing 1,00,000 record. I want to move record to `message_archives` from messages those are older than 30 days.

My Code:

```
$privateMsg = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE created < DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)");
if(mysql_num_rows($privateMsg)){
    while($getPrivateMsg=mysql_fetch_array($privateMsg)){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO message_archives SET user_id='".$getPrivateMsg['user_id']."', friend_id='".$getPrivateMsg['user_id']."', message='".$getPrivateMsg['message']."', is_view='0', created='".$getPrivateMsg['created']."'");

        mysql_query("DELETE FROM messages WHERE id='".$getPrivateMsg['id']."'");
    }
    echo "Message move to archives older than 30 days";
}else{
    echo "Error!! message not moved!!!.";
}
```

Above code working perfectly. But i need to customize my code. I need it in single query. Is there any shortcut way to single query?

Comment: if you mean "a single query to move the records from one table to another" that is not possible; you must insert the records into your archive table and then delete them from your messages table. The closest thing you can do is create a transaction

Comment: you can create an export job to csv/tsv file and delete the respective records from the messages table. In a separate query you can load the complete file using load infile option.

Comment: Yes i am first check the record is older than 30 days record exist or not. if exist then insert into message_archives table and delete these record messages table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest not loop over the result set to move them, but rather just use a single `INSERT` statement and a single `DELETE` statement:

```
INSERT INTO message_archives (user_id, friend_id, message, is_view, created)
SELECT user_id, user_id, message, 0, created
FROM messages 
WHERE created < DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)

DELETE FROM messages 
WHERE created < DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

BTW -- are you sure you want to insert `user_id` for both the `user_id` and `friend_id` fields? Perhaps that was a typo.

Comment: Hi @sgeddes recently i have added one column name `move_date` in the `message_archives` table. How to add current date while i am move record `messages` table to `message_archives` table?